# ArchUnit test importOptions DoNotIncludeTests not working

Tags: java, spring, testing, archunit

I'm using ArchUnit 0.18 and archunit-junit5 from a Spring 2.3.8 application. For some reason I can't find, `ImportOption.DoNotIncludeTests.class` is not working as expected and test classes are also included. I can only get the ArchUnit test working by commenting the code in those tests classes.

ArchUnit test is:

```java
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClasses;
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileImporter;
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ImportOption;
import com.tngtech.archunit.junit.AnalyzeClasses;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.petproject", importOptions = { ImportOption.DoNotIncludeTests.class })
class ArchitectureTest {

    @Test
    public void some_architecture_rule() {

        JavaClasses classes = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("com.petproject");

        layeredArchitecture()
                .layer("Controller").definedBy("com.petproject.controller")
                .layer("Validators").definedBy("com.petproject.validations.validators")
                .layer("Service").definedBy("com.petproject.service")
                .layer("Persistence").definedBy("com.petproject.repository")

                .whereLayer("Controller").mayNotBeAccessedByAnyLayer()
                .whereLayer("Service").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("Controller", "Validators")

                .check(classes);
    }
}
```

Am I missing some step in order to not get into account test classes?

Thanks!

Comment: I have just tried with JavaClasses classes = new ClassFileImporter().withImportOption(ImportOption.Predefined.DO_NOT_INCLUDE_TESTS).importPackages("com.petproject"); and now it works

Comment: How do you run your tests?

Answer (score 4):

The annotation `@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.petproject", importOptions = { ImportOption.DoNotIncludeTests.class })` is not evaluated in this case. First, the test method is annotated with JUnit's `@Test` instead of ArchUnit's `@ArchTest`. Second, the rule is checked against the result of

```java
JavaClasses classes = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("com.petproject");
```

As you already figured out, you could replace this with

```java
JavaClasses classes = new ClassFileImporter().withImportOption(ImportOption.Predefined.DO_NOT_INCLUDE_TESTS).importPackages("com.petproject");
```

Alternatively you could change your test setup to

```java
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.petproject", importOptions = { ImportOption.DoNotIncludeTests.class })
class ArchitectureTest {

    @ArchTest
    public static void some_architecture_rule(JavaClasses classes) {
        yourCreatedRule.check(classes);
    }

    // or as a field instead of a method

    @ArchTest
    public static ArchRule some_architecture_rule = ...
}
```